# how to write "show columns" mysql in zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Here is my query , I want to write it in zend framework inside model.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM  employee WHERE Field = 'status'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   function getstatusColumn()
   {
      $fieldname = 'status';
     $select = $this->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->quoteInto("SHOW COLUMNS FROM employee WHERE Field = ?",$fieldname);
     $select = $this->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
     foreach($select as $result)
     {   
         $r = $result['Type'];
         $enum = substr($r, 6, -2); 
         $values = explode("','", $enum); 

     }
     return $values;
```

}

This is what I did to get souliton for my question .
This I used to display the values in the drop down list.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `$this->getAdapter()->query($yourQuery)` to execute an arbitrary query on the current database.

Your function would thus look something like this:

```
public function getByField($fieldName){

$yourQuery=$this->getAdapter()->quoteInto("SHOW COLUMNS FROM  employee WHERE Field = '?'",$fieldname);

$query=$this->getAdapter()->query($yourQuery);

return $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($query);
}
```

This should do it quite nicely.

Comment: I get a fatal error  Fatal error: Call to undefined method User_Model_DbTable_Employee::quoteInto() . How can i solve this.This is my code   function getstatuscolumn()
      {  
         $fieldname = 'status';
         $yourQuery=$this->getDbTable()->quoteInto("SHOW COLUMNS FROM  employee WHERE Field = '?'",$fieldname);

        $query=$this->getDbTable()->query($yourQuery);

        return $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll($query);
      }

Comment: Don't do `getDbTable()`, do a `getAdapter()`. I don't know what `getDbTable()` is, but i assume that it returns a `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` object. What you want is a ` 
Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract` object. Try it EXACTLY as I wrote it.

Comment: I tried the same as you had given me the code , and I get a fatal error showing "Fatal error: Call to undefined method User_Model_Employee::getAdapter() in ". What you would suggest me to solve this problem . Thank you.

Comment: Does your model extend `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` ? If so, this should work. If not, your best chance is to save the database connection from initialization. In any case, you should either try using `getAdapter()` on  your database object, or skip it, and do `$this->fetchAll()`.

Comment: Yes my model extend zend_db_table_abstract . how could this problem be solved

Comment: As you can see from the docs [link](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/files/Db.Table.Abstract.html#\Zend_Db_Table_Abstract), if your object does extend `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`, than it should have this method. Please edit your question, and provide the class head ( the definition of its name and what it extends)

Comment: Ok . I did the same but again I find an error stating " Catchable fatal error: Object of class Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo could not be converted to string"